# flash[:notice] is throwing error when I use Ruby 1.9 with Rails 2.3.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

The Post pages I just generated using the scaffolding but they are not working When I try to access the New post page it give me the error.

Here is My layout code

```
    <p style="color: green"><%= flash[:message] %></p>
    <%= yield %>
```

Error that I get when i try to access the page

```
    Processing PostsController#new (for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-10-23 02:45:19) [GET]
    Rendering template within layouts/posts
    Rendering posts/new

 ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `^' for "4":String) on   line #12 of app/views/layouts/posts.html.erb:
    9: </head>
   10: <body>
   11: 
   12:p style="color: green"><%= flash[:message] %></p>
   13:   
   14: <%= yield %>
   15: 

app/views/layouts/posts.html.erb:12
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:29:in `new'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
/home/atta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/atta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/atta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Here is  the gem list that I am using with ruby 1.9

```
    actionmailer (2.3.4)
    actionpack (2.3.4)
    activerecord (2.3.4)
    activeresource (2.3.4)
    activesupport (2.3.4)
    bigdecimal (1.1.0)
    bundler-unload (1.0.2)
    executable-hooks (1.3.2)
    gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
    io-console (0.3)
    json (1.5.5)
    minitest (2.5.1)
    rack (1.0.1)
    rails (2.3.4)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    rdoc (3.9.5)
    rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
    rubygems-update (1.8.25)
    rvm (1.11.3.9)
    sqlite3 (1.3.12)
    sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
```

Note: I also downgraded my RubyGems to 1.8.25 as newer was not working with db:create rake command

Comment: These versions of **everything** are not supported for years now... Upgrade for common sense's sake

Comment: I agree but I am preparing my environment to work on a large and old project

Comment: Wow, that version of Rails is more than 7 years old.

Comment: I know .. i am embarrassed  but I need to setup this environment to make a legacy rails 2.3 app work

Answer (score 0):

In ruby 1.8 `"abc"[0]` returns ASCII code of the first character (integer number 97)
but in ruby 1.9 it returns string with the first character (string "a")

Integer number has method ^ but String doesn't.

You can try the following to fix this:

```
class String
  def ^(value)
    self.ord ^ value
  end
end
```

This is probably not the best solution (maybe better to patch some method in rails).

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading the Rails from 2.3.4 to 2.3.18 and rubyGems to 1.8.25 will fix the problem. Apparently Ruby 1.9.3 don't go well with 2.3.4